# Sort multiple column DataTable with string.Compare

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datatable

I would like to sort a `DataTable` for the first two columns using `string.Compare`, because I need to sort by Hungarian language (`"hu-HU_technl"`). (C#, .NET 2.0)

If not possible for the first two, is enough for the first column.

I tried [THIS](https://dotnetfiddle.net/39z2QX)...is working...but is with one column `DataTable` that I add to a `List<string>` and `Sort`:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu-HU_technl");

StringComparer comp = System.StringComparer.Create(ci, false);
        
List<string> fields = new List<string>();
DataTable dt = GetData();
        
for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    fields.Add(dt.Rows[row][0].ToString());
}

fields.Sort(
   delegate(string p1, string p2)
   {
       return string.Compare(p1, p2, false, ci); 
   }
);
        
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fields[i].ToString());
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/39z2QX

Sort multiple column `DataTable` for the first two columns using `string.Compare`.

Edit: code I tried

```
 //----------------------------------------------Main
    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn.ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dAdapter.Fill(ds, "Holtak");
 
    DataTable tempTable = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
 
    ds = utils.Settings.DataTableSort(ds, "hu-HU_technl");
 
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("imageUrl", typeof(byte[])));
 
//----------------------------------------------utils.Settings.DataTableSort
public static DataSet DataTableSort(DataSet dt, string culture)
{
    CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
    StringComparer comp = System.StringComparer.Create(ci, false);
 
    List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();
 
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        rows.Add(row);
    }
 
    rows.Sort(
        delegate(DataRow r1, DataRow r2)
        {
 
            int result = string.Compare((r1[2] == null ? "" : r1[2].ToString()), (r2[2] == null ? "" : r2[2].ToString()), false, ci);
 
            if (result == 0)
            {
                result = string.Compare((r1[3] == null ? "" : r1[3].ToString()), (r2[3] == null ? "" : r2[3].ToString()), false, ci);
            }
 
            return result;
        } 
    );
 
    DataSet dtresult = dt.Clone();
 
    foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
    {
        dtresult.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
    }
    
    return dtresult;
}
```

Comment: Post code with 2 column example so people can help you easier.

Comment: [DataTable.DefaultView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview); second example and Remarks section

Comment: @Jimi the problem is that I can't use LINQ, because I have an old app in .NET 2.0 C#

Comment: @Steve-M ADO.NET's DataView doesn't use LINQ. .NET Framework 2 isn't just old though, it's unsupported since 2011. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2.

Comment: The example AND the Remarks section (you didn't read that). See the `Sort()` method -- That LINQ is a just a loop that can in-line conditions -- You should most probably try and update your code anyway

Comment: As others said, post an actual example of the DataTable, data, and the desired outcome. DataView is available since the very first ADO.NET version. In all .NET versions you can use `view.Sort = "State ASC, ZipCode ASC";`

Comment: When comparing, use your custom comparer you've created earlier: `return comp.Compare(p1, p2);` instead of `return string.Compare(p1, p2, false, ci); `

Comment: @DmitryBychenko using your custom comparer helped me and jmcilhinney comment, now everything is working fine ♾️+. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the rows, sort the row, not the values from one column of the rows. When doing a comparison by two values, you do the first comparison and then, if the result is zero (i.e. the two values are equivalent), you do the second comparison.

```cs
List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();
DataTable dt = GetData();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    rows.Add(row);
}

rows.Sort(
        delegate(DataRow r1, DataRow r2)
        {
             int result = string.Compare((string)r1[0], (string)r2[0], false, ci);

             if (result == 0)
             {
                 result = string.Compare((string)r1[1], (string)r2[1], false, ci);
             }

             return result;
        }
);
```

Comment: here is my code that wrote based on your comment: (code)https://pastebin.com/8Ax7Pagq

Comment: @jjmcilhinney In VS 2005 the sorting is made like in this, online: [.net 5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/39z2QX), but if I try in [.NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JHKytC) its sorting correctly. here is my code that wrote based on your comment: (code)pastebin.com/8Ax7Pagq What could be the problem?

Comment: @Steve-M, don't post links to extremal sites in comments. Update your question.

Comment: @Steve-M Visual Studio is the editor, not the SDK or runtime. .NET 5 is NET Core 5, a completely different runtime from both .NET Framework 2 and .NET Framework 4.7. In fact, .NET Framework 2 and 4.x are different runtimes that can run side by side. You really need to pin down *which* runtime you're using. You've talked about 2.0 which is only needed in Windows XP, to 4.7 which is available on Windows 10 and 11, to .NET Core which can run on Windows

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET allowed sorting and filtering through DataViews since the very first .NET version. The syntax is similar to SQL. You can sort by last name in descending order like this :

```
var view = new DataView(dt);
view.Sort="LastName Desc,Name Asc";

foreach (DataRowView dataRow in view)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,4} {1,-10} {2}",dataRow["ID"], dataRow["Name"], dataRow["LastName"]);
}
```

By the way, .NET Framework 2 isn't just old, it's [discontinued since 2011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework). Chances are your application is running on 3.5 at least, as even Windows Vista came with .NET 3.0. The oldest supported .NET Framework version right now is 4.6.2

Comment: I tried with the DataView, but the sorting is not working as expected: [link to alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet)

Comment: So it does, work, but you want to use a CultureInfo different than the application's. You can change the DataTable's locale with the [DataTable.Locale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.locale?view=net-7.0) property

Comment: i didn't know of this (saved the link :)) and from what I see, it is working also under .NET 2.0, i will try out, thanks ♾️+